# Setting hourly email limit to delivery server via pmta config file

Tags: email, config, bulk-email, pmta

I have an email server with pmta. Someone recommended me to follow [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/IP_Management/ip_warmup_schedule.html) link for IP warmup in order to not get blacklisted. I am using mailwizz with 7 IPs.

I tried to set the delivery servers via `/etc/pmta/config`and changing the config file by adding   `max-msg-rate 25/h`.

I then reset `/etc/init.d/pmta restart`

I tried again but it is still exceeding the limit

Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`max-msg-rate 25/h` is a domain scoped directive, so you would need to apply this to each domain that you send to and `<domain *>`. I'm not sure about that directive specifically, but some require a reload and not a restart for the configuration change to take effect (specifically adding/changing the admin access IP for the PowerMTA web monitor).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `macro` as the follow:

```
<domain *>
    max-smtp-out 5
    max-msg-per-connection 20
    max-msg-rate 10000/d 
    bounce-after 12h
</domain>
```

For warming up you have to use the following delivery parameter

```
cold-virtual-mta [virtual-mta-here]
    <domain *>
        max-cold-virtual-mta-msg 1000/day
    </domain>
```

Regards!

Comment: Hi... I'm curios about warming up...
but when this will end?
Will I have to manually remove this part in the configuration file?
You have to make a macro as the follow:


cold-virtual-mta [virtual-mta-here]
    <domain *>
        max-cold-virtual-mta-msg 1000/day
    </domain>

Alen

Comment: Hey @ACaps, it’s not written in stone, you have to start a warming up process and you have to make sure the emails you will send to your recipients are desired to avoid spam flags or even spam traps. When you eventually get a good conversion rate, you can keep that customer, you have to be sure always you send curated healthy email traffic through the IP/IPs